# dd partition into file on block device level encrypted drive

Tags: encryption, dd

I need to make a backup of a partition which I usually do with:

```
dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/mnt/secret/sda1_back.img
```

The point is secret is a LUKS/dm-crypt block level encrypted device, is dd gonna mess with the encryption since it works so low, or is it gonna work fine since dd goes into a file?

I think I need to clarify my question: sda1 is not encrypted. I need to make a backup asap since sda is giving me I/O Errors. On `/mnt/secret` I have got a LUKS/dm-crypt encrypted device mounted. It's actually for other things, but it's the only place I have enough free space for the backup. My question is: after the above command, will I be able to read the .img file normally after I unlocked the LUKS container and mounted it? Or will it do something wrong to the LUKS container?

Comment: An encrypted system partition needs a non-encrypted `/boot` partition to boot. So, if your intention is cloning a system partition take that into consideration. The partition you're cloning itself will not be messed with because dd works with raw data, or *simply copies the block device* as stated in the first answer.

Comment: There's nothing low-level in your `of=`. You instructed `dd` to output whatever it reads from `/dev/sda1` to a file (a "real" one, not one under `/dev`), so no, nothing is gonna break.

Comment: This is the answer I needed, I was looking for! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

It's not gonna mess with the encryption - as dd simply copies the block device. However, the copy *will* be encrypted, and you need the passphrase or other unlock method to mount it.

You can, if you want an unencrypted backup, copy the mapped container instead.